# Mount point label randomly modified on mount

Tags: mountpoint

I have an external drive mounted that I want to mount at /media/Storage. I used disk utility and then gparted as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive to change the label of the drive to "Storage."  Whenever the drive mounts, however, it mounts at a location like /media/STORAGE_x. It has also been STORAG_x, and I think a "~u" was appended once. I really want it to be loaded explicitly at "/media/Storage". Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Link to gparted picture - sorry not enough rep to include it directly.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1aykxw94785twgd/-dev-sdb%20-%20GParted_001.png

Comment: You are using 12.04 or 12.10?

Comment: I am using 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update:

I think, your problem is with a bad FAT partitiion. Try formatting the partition using Disk-utility and give it a name too. Then mount the drive.

---

I think, you have already a folder in `/media` with the name `Storage`.

1. First remove the external drive
2. Then remove the folder

   sudo rmdir /media/Storage
3. Then insert the external drive again.

I think, it should solve the problem.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion, Anwar. Currently, only STORAGE_x shows up in my /media folder, but I did try umount and rmdir for /media/Storage and was told they did not exist. I also restarted, and my drive mounted at /media/STORAGE_x again.

Comment: @SamCopeland See the update.

Comment: True, reformatting solves it. It is properly mounted in /media/Storage now. Just have to copy the data back now. Many thanks!